# Netbeans 7.4 C++ hangs when I memory-map file?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

I am using the boost interprocess library to memory-map a 350MB file in to a char array using something like:

```
const char* FilePath = "file";
boost::shared_ptr<file_mapping> fm(new file_mapping(FilePath,read_only));
boost::shared_ptr<mapped_region> region(new mapped_region(*fm,read_only));

boost::shared_ptr<char> rawbytes(static_cast<char*>(region->get_address()));
```

when I put a break point after the last line and then try to add rawbytes to the watch window:

- I cannot see anything in the Watch window for rawbytes
- When I expanded rawbytes in the Watch window (to see the "value") my CPU fan started going crazy
- When I gave up and tried to stop debugging Netbeans wouldnt react to me killing the debug session. I had to close the whole Netbeans application instead.

I'd really like to use Netbeans on Linux (as I hate Eclipse CDT) so could someone please help me regarding these issues?

This is on Ubuntu 13.10